# Pygame unaccurate key press event handling

Tags: pygame, events

I have a problem with my `game_over()` function in Pygame.
When the player loses, the `game_over()` function gets executed but since that function has a key event queue, the player can quickly click on 'e' (the 'e' key starts a new round if the game is over), triggering a new round before the game over animation happens and I don't want that.

Instead, I want the game over animation to appear and then the user can click on any key he wants.

There is my `game_over` function:

```
def game_over():
    px_change, py_change = 0, 0
    pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.KEYDOWN)
    ...
    tsurface = MyFont.render('Game Over', True, (184, 15, 10))
    screen.blit(black_surface, (15, 146))
    screen.blit(tsurface, (32, 180))
    screen.blit(play_again_b, (280, 280))
    screen.blit(back_to_menu_b, (150, 280))
    clock.tick(1)
    pygame.event.set_allowed(pygame.KEYDOWN)
    if not pygame.event.get_blocked(pygame.KEYDOWN):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # some event handling code
```

So as you can see, what I tried is using the `pygame.event.set_blocked()` to disable `KEYDOWN` events, and then I enabled them right after blitting everything to the screen.
However, this didn't solve my issue and I still can't see the game_over screen if I click the 'e' key just when I lose.

So is there any solution ?

Comment: How is `game_over` called, how does it fit into your game loop, specially w.r.t. what the `e` key does?

Comment: @Vaillancourt the game_over() is called when the player loses, and I'm sure that the problem isn't there. And concerning the 'e' key, I had  specified what it does in the post before someone edited it! Anyway, it starts a new round

Comment: Logic would want to prevent a new round from being started right when the game over is detected. So the logic of your code would be something like "if game over detected, then set IS_GAME_OVER_ANIMATION = True, and then call game_over()" and somewhere else "if key pressed == 'e', and if IS_GAME_OVER_ANIMATION == False, then restart a new round". Without knowing more of your code, the help we can provide is limited.

Comment: I'll try that !

Comment: @Vaillancourt it didn't work , it's the same as what I've done before in the code block mentionned in the post

Comment: One thing you can do, if you have not already done so, is look up the State Machine pattern, where you split your game states nicely. (An answer has been [written about it](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/193978/40264) recently.) With this, you would split your gameover animation into its own state and that would prevent the user from hitting any key because it is not allowed in the game.

Comment: Okay, well you'll have to provide [more code](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/whats-a-minimum-complete-verifiable-example-mcve-and-how-do-i-provide-it) because I don't see how we could reproduce the issue you're currently experiencing with the code you have provided so far.

Comment: @Vaillancourt other parts of the code aren't related to this question. Maybe the only one that has to do with it is the call of game_over(). However, the code calling that function is simple and clear that it can't result in such issue. For the game I'm currently working on, that's an advanced version of the OG snake game, the game_over() function gets executed if the player reaches the boundaries of the screen, or he collides with one of the danger items such as a cactus. That's all. so the blocks of code in which game_over() is called have this pattern : if (condition): game_over()

Comment: The code that creates the new round may be involved in the issue. If the `e` is in the event queue just before the game_over function is invoked, the issue might be coming from there too.

Comment: @Vaillancourt I think I found the origin of the problem but I'm not pretty sure yet. It's maybe because I have an event loop in the main while loop and that other event loop in the game_over() function. Normally, pygame.event.get() should be called once. So that should have smth to do with the issue.

Comment: That's something I wanted to mention but I did not have time before. Having more than one way to process events seems odd. It should be handled only at one place, in the main loop.